# Can't write file to server via either Samba or NFS

Tags: mount, samba, nfs

I have setup Ubuntu 12.0.4 Server 32-bit on a home PC and am trying to simply share a basic file directory on that server for read-write access from a Ubuntu 12.0.4 64-bit client (via NFS and Samba - and only reason I'm trying both is that I can't get NFS to work, so tried Samba, and both are giving me the same results 'Permission denied').

In both instances from the client (NFS  and Samba) I can successfully connect to the fileshare, but both NFS and Samba 'tell me' I can't write to it 'permission denied'.  I've tried to avoid the server side chmod 777 route and give anyone god access to destroy all of my server files in one click, so I'm looking for (what I'm hoping is) a more sophisticated and appropriate approach to do this.

Comment: Hi! You will get more attention if you stop writing stories and just mention the *error* (not the *situation*). Otherwise, it would be hard to get any response. I recommend to you to edit this and be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, Lucio.  I was trying to provide all info I could to help clarify.  I can look to cut it down.

Comment: Cut down description to simplify problem statement per Lucio's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was with file directory ownership.   'root' was the owner of file directory.  I used chown to change directory ownership to user and usergroup that I am sharing files with and read/write then worked from all laptops.